# Python version running on EMR 6.8

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

What version of Python does EMR 6.8 support?

It looks like previous versions of EMR supported Python 3.7 which will be deprecated in 6 months.

EMR 6.8 runs Spark 3.3.0 which supports Python up to 3.9.

I can't find the answer on the official release guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-680-release.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'previous versions of EMR supported Python 3.7 which will be deprecated in 6 months.'  EMR 6.8.0 does support Python 3.7.  Are you referring to a different version of EMR?"

Comment: https://endoflife.date/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was asked, they have updated the page at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-app-versions-6.x.html with the information you are looking for.  There is now a line item for included Python version.

emr-6.8.0 includes Python versions 2.7, 3.7.

As of today, the latest EMR version is emr-6.14.0 which still only includes Python 3.7.

Comment: Correct and the issue here is that EMR pushes pyspark built for Python-3.7 which is not compatible with later versions of Python. I have tried adding different python on the custom EMR AMI and got the infamous "required field "type_ignores" missing from Module" error. There was some change introduced in Python 3.8 (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters I believe) that triggers this error on a older python packages.

Comment: Another problem is vulnerabilities in some Python packages running in Python 3.7, upgrading to fix them need at least Python 3.8. AWS EMR team should do something about this!

Answer (score 2):

- EMR 6.8.0 aligns with Spark/PySpark 3.3.0, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-6x.html
- PySpark 3.3.0 supports Python 3.7 and up, according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/getting_started/install.html#python-version-supported
- *and up* certainly means 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10, as those are the stable and currently supported releases of Python according to their respective release schedule PEPs:

  - 3.10 PEP 619
  - 3.9 PEP 596
  - 3.8 PEP 569
  - 3.7 PEP 537

Which Python is available to you is a question about which compute you're using in EMR to run PySpark. If you want another Python, you may need to pick another AMI, a different container image, or talk to AWS directly.

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this issue of needing to run a different Python version on EMR. The following code block should install Python 3.9 and then let you install additional dependencies if you add pip install commands afterwards. Then when trying to trigger Spark jobs in an EMR step, use Spark Submit with the PYSPARK_PYTHON arg pointing to Python 3.9, and you'll be fine. I think my PYSPARK_PYTHON arg is set with `--conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/local/bin/python3.9`

```
# Set Python to autolocate Python 3.9
PYTHON='$(which python3.9)'

# Install necessary Python and Spark Dependencies
# This code works on EC2 instances by default.
sudo yum -y install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel git

# Collect Python 3.9.16
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.16/Python-3.9.16.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.9.16.tgz

# Install Python 3.9.16
cd Python-3.9.16
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall

# Setup Python 3.9 Pip to install future dependencies added
sudo $PYTHON -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34682068)